# encapsulate a html tag with another tag, using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

For example I have this code...

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <!--other tags-->
    <div class="innerdiv">
        <!--other tags-->
        <fieldset>
            <!--other tags-->
            <!--one start-->
            <fieldset>
            <!--other tags-->
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="myclass">
            <!--other tags-->
            </fieldset>
            <!--one end-->
        </fieldset>

        <!--two start-->
        <fieldset>
        <!--other tags-->
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="myclass">
        <!--other tags-->
        </fieldset>
        <!--two end-->

        <!--two start-->
        <fieldset>
        <!--other tags-->
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="myclass">
        <!--other tags-->
        </fieldset>
        <!--two end-->

        <fieldset>
            <!--other tags-->
            <!--one start-->
            <fieldset>
            <!--other tags-->
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="myclass">
            <!--other tags-->
            </fieldset>
            <!--one end-->
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="innerdiv">
        <!--other tags-->
        <!--two start-->
        <fieldset>
        <!--other tags-->
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="myclass">
        <!--other tags-->
        </fieldset>
        <!--two end-->

        <fieldset>
            <!--other tags-->
            <!--one start-->
            <fieldset>
            <!--other tags-->
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="myclass">
            <!--other tags-->
            </fieldset>
            <!--one end-->
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see one and two are exactly the same, however I want two to be encapsulated also by a fieldset. I can do this with jquery right?..but how?

## Update

Updated code because there isn't only two of them..hehe and there other tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to wrap two elements with one structure, you're going to need to use [`.wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/). You can't use `.wrap` because that wraps the HTML around *each* matched element, not around *all* of the matched elements. The first thing that came to my mind was this:

```
$("#firstFieldset").next().andSelf().wrapAll("<fieldset>");
```

Given the HTML:

```
<fieldset id="firstFieldset"></fieldset>
<fieldset class="myclass"></fieldset>
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/frw8j/5/) (inspect the source of the output window). What it does is select the first fieldset, get the following sibling, add the original one back into the matched set of elements and wrap the entire matched set in a `fieldset`.

**Update** based on comments

```
var yourFieldset = $("#mydiv > fieldset:first").next();
yourFieldset.next().andSelf().wrapAll("<fieldset>");
```

The first line gets the first `fieldset` which is a direct child of `#mydiv`, then gets the next sibling which is the first `fieldset` of your second set.

Comment: Is that so...then this would be the correct one. But how do I select the correct fieldset?

Comment: Well the easiest way is to give it an `id`. Or can you not modify the HTML?

Comment: I can't modify the HTML..that's why my guess is that this would be done with jquery.

Comment: It didn't work, the fieldset with class inside one has been affected. And the fieldset wrapping didn't include the fieldset with class on two. Also it only works and the 2nd fieldset..hehehe

Comment: Correction..the `wrapAll()` works great! but the selector doesn't select the correct one.

Comment: This is the code I came up with:

`var $innerdiv = $("#outerdiv .innerdiv");
        $innerdiv.each(function(){
            var $fieldset1 = $(this).children("fieldset");
            $fieldset1.not(":has(fieldset)").each(function(){
                var $fieldset2 = $(this).not("*.my_class");
                
                $fieldset2.next("fieldset[*.myclass]").andSelf().wrapAll("<fieldset class='g_inline'><ol>"); 
            });
        });`

Answer (score 4):

try http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ ?

```
<script>$("p").wrap("<div></div>");</script>
```

Comment: The OP wants to wrap two individual `fieldset` elements in *one* more `fieldset`. This would wrap each of them separately.